Implementing idempotency on the server using hypermedia in REST API
Suppose I'm creating a REST API and my POST method creates a new Order. And I'd like to use Hypermedia in my API, supplying a list of available actions to the client, and path to a POST method should contain IdempotencyKey (so IdempotencyKey is created on the server, not on the client). For example:
{
  // ...
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "createOrder",
      "path": "/api/v1/orders/create/<idempotency-key-uuid>",
      "method": "POST"
    }
  ]
}


How would you actually get this initial response if a user lands right on to the "Create Order" page? Should I issue some kind of get request when the page is initially loaded (to get the path of "createOrder" action)?

What happens when user clicks on "Create" button, so the POST request is issued, and then something bad happened (lost connection, timeout of some kind). The client does not get any response but the new Order is still created. The user refreshes the page to try again (to create Order). We should get the new IdempotencyKey if the order has been created, and the same IdempotencyKey if it hasn't, right? Is there any way to generate the same or the new IdempotencyKey on the server depending on what actually happened?


Looks like it must depend on the state of the server, but I can't really figure out what the right implementation would be.

I've never come across the idea of having an IdempotencyKey specifically - assuming it's distinct from an ObjectKey / UniqueID / EntityKey.
If an object's uniqueness is controlled by the server then typically a client would simply call /api/v1/orders/create so that "the server" can do its thing. including generating a new unique ID, which the response might include in the metadata.

How would you actually get this initial response if a user lands right on to the "Create Order" page?

Dunno - sounds complicated and brittle.  I'd need to know why such an approach was needed over the more usual approach I described above.  I'm assuming the goal is to avoid creating duplicate Objects if two very similar 'create' requests get sent by accident?

The user refreshes the page to try again (to create Order). We should get the new IdempotencyKey if the order has been created, and the same IdempotencyKey if it hasn't, right?

Approach A: This accepted answer here suggests that the client sets a unique ID, to whatever it likes, and the server knows to only ever allow one instance thereof (to enforce uniqueness, that doesn't mean it has to generate it). I'm unclear if the ID that answer refers to is the ObjectID or a IdempotencyKey.  In your scenario you would want to keep the same IdempotencyKey otherwise it will look like a new request.
Other answers from that same question discuss POE, which seems to be along the lines you were originally suggesting.
Approach B: Ensure the server-side service has sufficient smarts to see if the incoming data was already in existence, this could be based just on the incoming objects data, or could also take information like the requests date/time and the objects created date/time into account.
Update - Extra Thoughts
The difference between approaches A & B is that with B you are essentially checking against the actual data (presumably in the System of Record i.e. the master), with A you're only validating client requests, which are partially outside your control (you can tell API clients what to do but you can't control how they do it, beyond what your API can enforce).
With B the onus is on the service to ensure the consistency of the data, meaning it (by design) will/should assume API callers have no idea what they are doing.  With A you'll only be able to do this if the idempotency is enforced by the server - meaning both the client and server need to work together.  E.g. what happens if some naughty client-request is missing the IdempotencyKey?  Will you/the server reject the request?  What happens if some lazy client-app coder just hard-codes the same value - or if two clients accidentally submit clashing IdempotencyKey?

As Adrian K has mentioned in his post the current best practice / standard is that the request id is generated by the client and servers have to make sure that the request is handled in an idempotent way.
Theory
Whenever you have a transient issue then you want to perform a retry to make sure that your request is received and processed by the servers. The issue could happen at several places:

Between the client and the server: the request never reaches the server
On the server: the request reaches the server but it could not be processed
Between the server and the client: the request is received and processed but the response never reaches the client

For the first scenario you don't need idempotency at all, since nothing has happened on the server-side.
In case of server failure it might happen that during the request processing some permanent but partial change has been made. It's the server's responsibility to do the cleanup and do not have inconsistent state. So, yet again, we are not talking about idempotency here.
The only case when we need idempontency is when the server did its job but the client does not receive any confirmation / acknowledgement about it. So, the client wants to perform a retry to make sure that the request is received and processed by the servers. Whenever a retry attempt is issued then the server has to identify that this request is the exact same one that I have seen and processed before. In this case the server does not process the request against (to avoid unwanted side-effects) but returns the exact same response as it was the original request.
Practice
Client-side
The client generates an unique request id. I have seen two approaches here. One simply generates an UUIDv4. The other technique timestamps the request body and generates an MD5 hash from it. I personally prefer the former one due its simplicity.
The client then adds this request id to the request headers. This unique request id should not be part of the request path or request body. It is a metadata about the request so, the perfect place for this is the request headers. With this approach the path and the body are kept clean.
Whenever a retry attempt is made the same request id should be used.
Server-side
This can be implemented in many ways but the most common approach what I have seen is the usage of a deduplication cache. Whenever a request is received by the server it does perform a cache lookup.
If the request id is not present then the server processes the request and stores the request id in the cache. If the request id is present then the server does not process the request just constructs the response.
One thing it is worth mentioning: the cache expiration. Each request id should be stored in the cache at least N minutes. N should be greater than all the attempts in total.
Let's suppose your client has following resilience mechanisms in place:

a 1 minute request timeout
a retry logic with at most 3 attempts

with fix half minute delay between attempts



That means we have at most 4 attempts (the original request + the three retries): 4 * 1min + 3 * 0.5min = 5.5 mins. So, it is advisable to set a TTL to at least 5.5 mins on each request id.
